# Is there any way to create a cmake project with several files in visual studio 2022 which contain a main function in each of them?

Tags: visual-studio

How can I make several files in a cmake projec in visual studio 2022 t which contain each their main function?

I exepect to make a cmake project for my thesis since the semester is ending up the next moth and I would like to be helped by you people

Comment: An executable is allowed only one main, so unless all the files are for separate programs, this isn't doable. If the files are built into individual programs (each with their own main), then cmake will do it just fine - just create each program as a separate target, and then create a full build target that creates all of those individual targets.

Comment: If your next question is *Can you help me write it?*, the answer is yes, once you've made an effort to do so yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your make file, and ask a specific question related to its contents, and we can try to help. Also, just an FYI - your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.